# How to use documents linking with rethinkdb?

Tags: c#, database, relational-database, rethinkdb

I'm using Rethink DB with C# via RthinkDB.Driver https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver.

I know that in relational databases there is a feature to create references in one document to another. In mongodb it is ObjectID, in LiteDB it is BsonRef attribute or Dbref function. 
LiteDB example:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [BsonRef("customers")] // where "customers" are Customer collection name
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The question is, how i can declare reference of object to another table?
I read this article https://rethinkdb.com/docs/data-modeling/#linking-documents-in-multiple-tables but there are no examples how to insert documents with references.

Answer (score 1):

The c# driver don't expose annotations for your classes. RethinkDB is only storing json documents that can be queried with relations. Consider writting a little ORM, or comment your classes attributes.